# How to connect to Sp from Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have SP's written in SQL server. When i connect to Tableau I have to use these SPs. How to pass values to SP in tableau?
Any help about this concern is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/connect_basic_stored_procedures.html

Basically, you add the stored procedure into the data source and then you create parameters in tableau and use them to execute the stored procedure.

> From the left pane, drag the procedure to the canvas or double-click
>   one of the listed procedures. If parameters are available in the
>   procedure, the Parameters dialog box automatically displays.  Instead
>   of entering a value, you can use an existing Tableau parameter, or
>   create a new Tableau parameter for the value:
>
> If you then expose the Tableau parameter in the view, users are able
>   to change the value of the parameter in the procedure interactively.